# How to render image in my Django Blog Template?

Tags: django

Hi Guys I have a blog setup and I want to add the ability for an image or thumbnail to be included in every blog post. I'm having trouble getting the location of the file and the blog template to match up and show the image. I'm also having difficulties integrating the ImageWithThumbnail model to the Entry model.

post.html

```
    {% include 'head.html' %}
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% load django_markdown %}

<div class="container">

  <div class="post">
    <h2><a href="{% url "entry_detail" slug=object.slug %}">{{ object.title }}</a></h2>

    <p class="meta">
      {{ object.created }} |
      Tagged under {{  object.tags.all|join:", " }} <p> Created by
      {{ object.author }} </p>
    </p>
    {{ object.body|markdown }}
<img src="{% static "{{ STATIC_ROOT }}/media/tableau_public.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
{{ object.file }}


</div>


{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

Settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for vizualytic project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '#ic_*)dw$fxp+p_c=3e=91ujzivxurqf7y7572z9&sfs19aek%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_markdown',
    'website',
    'blog',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'vizualytic.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'vizualytic.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static-only")
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static"),
    )
```

view.py

```
from django.views import generic
from . import models


class BlogIndex(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.Entry.objects.published()
    template_name = "blog.html"
    paginate_by = 3


class BlogDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Entry
    template_name = "post.html"
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings


class Tag(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug


class EntryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def published(self):
        return self.filter(publish=True)


class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    file = models.ImageField()
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT+"/%Y/%m/%d",max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    objects = EntryQuerySet.as_manager()

    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("entry_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog Entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
        ordering = ["-created"]


class ImageWithThumbnail(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to="/%Y/%m/%d",max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
     thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="/%Y/%m/%d",max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)

     def create_thumbnail(self):
         # original code for this method came from
         # http://snipt.net/danfreak/generate-thumbnails-in-django-with-pil/

         # If there is no image associated with this.
         # do not create thumbnail
         if not self.image:
             return

         from PIL import Image
         from cStringIO import StringIO
         from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
         import os

         # Set our max thumbnail size in a tuple (max width, max height)
         THUMBNAIL_SIZE = (200,200)

         DJANGO_TYPE = self.image.file.content_type

         if DJANGO_TYPE == 'image/jpeg':
             PIL_TYPE = 'jpeg'
             FILE_EXTENSION = 'jpg'
         elif DJANGO_TYPE == 'image/png':
             PIL_TYPE = 'png'
             FILE_EXTENSION = 'png'

         # Open original photo which we want to thumbnail using PIL's Image
         image = Image.open(StringIO(self.image.read()))

         # Convert to RGB if necessary
         # Thanks to Limodou on DjangoSnippets.org
         # http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/20/
         #
         # I commented this part since it messes up my png files
         #
         #if image.mode not in ('L', 'RGB'):
         #    image = image.convert('RGB')

         # We use our PIL Image object to create the thumbnail, which already
         # has a thumbnail() convenience method that contrains proportions.
         # Additionally, we use Image.ANTIALIAS to make the image look better.
         # Without antialiasing the image pattern artifacts may result.
         image.thumbnail(THUMBNAIL_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)

         # Save the thumbnail
         temp_handle = StringIO()
         image.save(temp_handle, PIL_TYPE)
         temp_handle.seek(0)

         # Save image to a SimpleUploadedFile which can be saved into
         # ImageField
         suf = SimpleUploadedFile(os.path.split(self.image.name)[-1],
                 temp_handle.read(), content_type=DJANGO_TYPE)
         # Save SimpleUploadedFile into image field
         self.thumbnail.save('%s_thumbnail.%s'%(os.path.splitext(suf.name)[0],FILE_EXTENSION), suf, save=False)

     def save(self):
         # create a thumbnail
         self.create_thumbnail()

         super(ImageWithThumbnail, self).save()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you just need:

```
<img src="{{ object.thumbnail.url }}" alt="My image"/>
```

note that the `{% static 'file.extension' %}` is used only to render static files.

Comment: Hi I tired it <img src="/media/{{ object.file }}" alt="My image"/> however it doesnt work for me. I changed /media/ to /static/ and moved the files and it worked for some reason the template is not recognizing /media/ folder. Is my settings setup wrong STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static-only")
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static"),

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [Django Filer](https://django-filer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with [Easy Thumbnails](https://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/2.1/).

You will only need one image field in your model and leave making the thumbnail to Easy Thumbnails on rendering of the template.